# How to add Div inside Div Dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a Div in which I want to add another small Div's Dynamically. But small Div's strictly needs to be inside the main Div. I have added one small Div inside. But how to add all the 15 div's inside the main Div dynamically I'm not getting. Also the size of small Div's are fixed, if they are more in numbers say 20, then Main Div should have horizontal scroll bar.

Here is the HTML used:

```
 <div id="tables" style="width:740px; height:50px; border:1px solid;margin-left:180px;">

 <div id ="1" style="border:1px solid; height:44px; width:50px; margin-left:2px; margin-top:2px; margin-bottom:2px;">1</div>

 </div>
```

And here is my fiddle link: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mp6dp5jm/).

Comment: You haven't tried nothing in this fiddle

Comment: @Jai that's now valid in HTML5

Comment: pls avoid inline-styles, use css-classes instead so your code gets more readable.
For your problem look at the [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function from jQuery

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i know but need to know from PritishKumar.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I didn't know that they made it valid. Do you have a link to the specification?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan nevermind got it http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop as many times as required, create the elements and then append them to `#tables`. Something like this:

```
var $tables = $('#tables');
for (var i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
    $('<div />', { class: 'inner', text: i }).appendTo($tables);
};
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mp6dp5jm/1/)

You can add the `id` property back in if needed, but I would advise against incremental `id` attributes as they only lead to a maintenance headache. Also, I changed the styling to use actual CSS classes for a better separation of concerns.

Comment: Thanks a lot! for your answer ..Will you please tell me how to put the dynamic div horizontally inside the Main Div instead of vertically as is shown in fiddle..

Comment: I hope Rory will leave that job to you :)

Comment: @Pritishkumar use CSS, `display: inline-block` or `float: left`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you I tried your css but first 5 div's are coming inside the parent Div rest are coming down in new row whereas i am trying to add this in same Parent Div with Horizontal Scroll Bar..

Comment: You should start a new question for this problem, as it is related to CSS, not jQuery or javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code in `jQuery` to append a div :

```
smallDivWidth =  (740 / 15);

for (var i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
    $('#tables').append('<div style="border:1px solid; height:44px;float:left; margin- left:2px; margin-top:2px; margin-bottom:2px;">1</div>');
$('#tables').children().css('width',(smallDivWidth-4)+'px');
};
```

Just as an example, see this here :

```js
$("#btnDynamicDiv").click(function() {
    var smallDivWidth =  (740 / 15);
    for (var i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
        $('#tables').append('<div style="border:1px solid; height:44px;float:left; margin- left:2px; margin-top:2px; margin-bottom:2px;">1</div>');
        $('#tables').children().css('width',(smallDivWidth-4)+'px');
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tables" style="width:740px; height:50px; border:1px solid;margin-left:180px;">

 <div id ="1" style="border:1px solid; height:44px; width:50px; margin-left:2px; margin-top:2px; margin-bottom:2px;">1</div>

 </div>
<input type="button" id="btnDynamicDiv" value ="Add div dynamically"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this (**[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mp6dp5jm/8/)**)

HTML:

```
<div id="tables">
    <div class="inner" id="innder-1">1</div>
</div>

<div class="inner inner-template"></div>

<br>
<button id="add-btn">Add inner</button>
```

CSS:

```
#tables {
    width:200px; 
    height:50px; 
    border:1px solid;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.inner {
    border:1px solid;
    height:44px;
    width:50px;
    margin-left:2px;
    margin-top:2px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    white-space: howrap;
}

.inner-template {
   display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
var $template = $('.inner-template');

$('#add-btn').on('click', function() {
    var currentID = $('#tables .inner').length + 1;
    var $inner = $template
        .clone()
        .removeClass('inner-template')
        .attr('id', 'inner-' + currentID)
        .text(currentID)
        .appendTo('#tables');
});
```